# How to convert annual data to quarterly data in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[sample data to convert from annual to quarterly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwsmp.png)I need some help on how I can convert annual data in excel. My annual data ranges from 2016 to 2021 for 27 countries but some years in some countries have missing data, and I want to get quarterly data starting 2017 to 2021.
Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would be able to calculate yearly from quarterly, but not from yearly to quarterly. We can't tell if the first quarter was higher compared to the second/third/last quarter.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quarterly data. You know that the `2017` value is `90,3885`, but you don't have more data about each quarter of `2017`.

Comment: Yeah, I do not have any other data for each year. Only the annual data.

Comment: So you cannot do it! do you want to use `Value / 4`?